# how to use large array with ngfor in angular 5

Tags: html, angular, dom, browser

When i display more than 100 products with ngfor page is very slow.
Is there any problem about  performance on browser   if call a method inside ngFor with one hundred items  or  set a lot of elements inside ngFor for one item?

here is my  typescript code that i get some products from server with http post request

```
public  products:any = [] ;

constructor(
  private setRouter: SetRouterService,
  private header :HeaderService,
  private cdr:  ChangeDetectorRef,
  private router : Router,
  private crypto:EncryptDecryptService ,
  private dataservices: DataService ,
  private Httpservice :HttpService ,
  private route: ActivatedRoute
) {


this.dataservices.update_loader(true);

this.dataservices.create_object_request( 'products', { 'type': 'default', 'number_click': 1 }  );

this.my_products = this.Httpservice.Http_Post( this.dataservices.object_request ) // make request ......

    .subscribe( //  take success

        data => {

          if ( data['status'] == 'product' ) {

            this.products = data['data']['products'];

            this.build_pages_link( data['data']['pages_details']);

            this.dataservices.update_loader(false);

          }
        },
        error => console.log( error['data'] ) // take error .....

    );


}
```

here is my html code that i display products with ngFor

```
  <div class="width_products  products-animation " *ngFor="let product of products ; let i = index"  [ngClass]="{ 'width_products_open_menu':header.status_menu  }" >

      <div class="each_width_product" >

          <div class="title_products more_detail_product" (click)="set_router({ path:product['company'].company_name+'/'+product.product_title , data:product.product_id , relative:true })">

              {{product.product_title }}

          </div>


          <div class="dropdown_products">

              <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down"></span>

          </div>

          <div class="date_products">

              <span class='glyphicon glyphicon-time'></span> {{product.product_date}}

          </div>

          <div class="image_profile_company " (click)="set_router({ path:product['company'].company_name , data: product['company'].company_id , relative:true })">

              <img  class="image_prof_admin" src="../../assets/images/products_image/{{product['company'].company_image}}">

          </div>

          <div class="image_product_primary  " (click)="set_router({ path:product['company'].company_name+'/'+product.product_title , data:product.product_id , relative:true })">

              <img class="image_product img_primary_product{{product.product_id}}" src="../../assets/images/products_image/{{product.product_image}}">

          </div>

          <div class="wish_list hover_all_wish notCloseDropdawnFavorite notCloseDropdawnCard" (mouseleave)="mouseLeave_wish( product )"  (mouseenter) ="mouseHover_wish( product ,i )"  id="wish_list{{product.product_id}}" (click)="header.add_wish_list( product )" [ngClass]="{'wish_list_hover': product_properties.index_product == i }">

          </div>

          <div class="about_wish" >

              <div class="wish_list_write">

                  <div class="plus_icon">{{dataservices.language.add_wishlist}}</div>

              </div>

              <div class="wish_list_icon">

                  <button mat-mini-fab class="button_heart"  >

                      <div *ngIf="header.wish_properties.wishList.length > 0; else  emtyWish " >

                          <div *ngIf="check_wish( product ) ; else notinwish">

                              <mat-icon>favorite</mat-icon>

                          </div>

                          <ng-template #notinwish >

                              <mat-icon class="notCloseDropdawnFavorite notCloseDropdawnCard"  [ngClass]="{'hide_border_heart'  : product_properties.hover_wish_list && product_properties.index_product == i } ">favorite_border</mat-icon>

                              <mat-icon class="hearts_div_hover notCloseDropdawnFavorite notCloseDropdawnCard" [ngClass]="{'show_full_heart'  : product_properties.hover_wish_list && product_properties.index_product == i } ">favorite</mat-icon>

                          </ng-template>

                      </div>

                      <ng-template #emtyWish>

                          <mat-icon  [ngClass]="{'hide_border_heart'  : product_properties.hover_wish_list && product_properties.index_product == i } ">favorite_border</mat-icon>

                          <mat-icon class="hearts_div_hover" [ngClass]="{'show_full_heart'  : product_properties.hover_wish_list && product_properties.index_product == i } ">favorite</mat-icon>

                      </ng-template>

                  </button>

              </div>

          </div>

          <div class="footer_products">

                <span matTooltip="Views!">

                    <div class="button_footer_products">

                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open icon_eye"></span>

                        <div class="both_write ">

                            12889

                        </div>

                    </div>

                </span>

              <span matTooltip="Add to your card"  class="notCloseDropdawnCard notCloseDropdawnFavorite " (click)="header.add_cart_list( product )">


                  <div class="button_footer_products">

                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus icon_eye notCloseDropdawnCard notCloseDropdawnFavorite" *ngIf="!check_cart( product ) ; else incart "></span>

                      <ng-template  #incart>

                          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon glyphicon-ok icon_eye notCloseDropdawnCard notCloseDropdawnFavorite"></span>

                      </ng-template>

                      <div class="both_write ">

                          Cart

                      </div>

                  </div>

              </span>

              <span matTooltip="See Details!">

                  <div (click)="set_router({ path:product['company'].company_name+'/'+product.product_title , data:product.product_id , relative:true })" class="button_footer_products more_detail_product" id="<?php echo $result_all_products['id'] ?>">

                      <span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-option-horizontal icon_eye"></span>

                      <div class="both_write ">

                          More
                      </div>

                  </div>

              </span>

          </div>

          <div class="prise_products">

              Price:

              <div class="both_prise_products prise_primary">

                  <del>$2500</del>

              </div>

              <div class="both_prise_products prise_secondary">

                  $3500

              </div>

          </div>

          <div class="plus_height"></div>

      </div>

  </div>
```

what should i do to solve it ? thank you.

Comment: This is a pretty generic question.  Can you provide your code?  without it its hard to tell where the issue lies.

Comment: Hi, check out this article to learn about asking questions on StackOverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: ok thank you for it i have edit my question, but  can anyone help me ?

Answer (score 3):

the problem is the code of your function is execute every time that you do something in the template (mouse moved, for example). The lifecycle of the template is causing this,add to that the fact that your are creating a instance of that function for every item in your array. I suggest you try to

1- change the change detection strategy of component

```
Component({
   ...,
   changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
MyComponent {}
```

2- reduce the number of call from your template to methods in your component (try to use pipe instead if can be applied)

Comment: i did it  , but nothing  happend same result .

Comment: @KlodianShaba what do you do exactly?

Comment: check_wish() method has been called multiple times, put a console.log inside, you will see

Comment: Exactly i get one hundred products from server and display them   in browser  ,  every product have  two options add to wishList and add to cartList  , if click  add  to wish or cart   added  this item in selected card or wish and check  if is add or not in wish or in cart , but now i have  remove all these controllers and agan is slow performace   with one houndred products .

Comment: Don’t download all the products. Try to use pagination or infinity scroll because that can be a problem is the product object is to heavy

Comment: I have did pagination  every page have 100 products.

Comment: Helped to my problem -> havy operations in ngFor. Thank you +1